# Trouble with mysqldump when backing up db as xml

Tags: php, xml, shell, mysql

I'm trying to backup one of my databases with `mysqldump` and I'm trying to export it to an xml file which already exists. Here is what I have:

```
<?php
$dbUser = 'user';    // db User
$dbPass = 'pass';    // db User Password
$dbName = 'db';      // db name
$dest   = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'backup'; // Path to directory

class MySQLDump {
private $cmd;

function MySQLDump($dbUser,$dbPass,$dbName,$dest) {
    $fname = $dbName.'.xml';
    $this->cmd='mysqldump -X -u'.$dbUser.' -p'.$dbPass.' '.$dbName.
        ' >'.$dest.'/'.$fname;
}

public function backup() {
    system($this->cmd, $error);
    if($error) {
        trigger_error ('Backup failed: ' . $error . '<br />Attempted: ' . $this->cmd);
    }
}
} // end class def

$mysqlDump = new MySQLDump($dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName, $dest);  
$mysqlDump->backup();
?>
```

This always generates the error thrown in the `backup` function. Here is a sample of `$cmd`'s output:

```
mysqldump -X -udan -pdanPass danDB >/var/www/prod/dan/web/backup/danDB.xml
```

Any idea what's going wrong? I've never really used `mysqldump` so I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding a space between `-u` and your `$dbUser`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I tried putting a space between just the -u and the username and between both -u and -p but neither got it working.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Does mysqldump return a status?](https://serverfault.com/q/249853/69499) something is going wrong, yes. We can not say if a warning or an error because you didn't share the return code.

Apart from that you can easily learn what exactly goes wrong by looking into [STDERR output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364180/stderr-what-is-it-what-are-its-common-uses) returned from the `mysqldump` command. E.g. you can pipe it into `database.err`:

```
mysqldump -X -udan -pdanPass danDB >/path/to/backup/danDB.xml 2>database.err
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score -1):

This one work for me

```
mysqldump --user=xxx --password=xxx  databasename  --xml > file.xml
```