# Usage of stderr in C

Tags: c, file-io, stderr

I am trying to use stderr but i am totally confused with respect to its usage.I was about to [reply to a question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364180/stderr-what-is-it-what-are-its-common-uses) but when i think to try it first , i find myself stucked.

I read about [stderr  in this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stderr/),and as per the information i tried to use it like this

```
FILE *stderr;

stderr = fopen("<path to file>","w");

.....//some code and conditions
fprintf(stderr,"found a error here");
```

using this gives me a seg fault, which i wasn't able to figure out why?

then i used [freopen()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/), then also i get the seg fault.Is stderr byitself send the standard err if any to some default file instead of stdout.

Here is my code in which i am only trying to use stderr as any other FILE * pointer.May i am totlly takingit as wrong way to execute.Or it only write standard compiler errors to some default file.Need help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>
FILE *stderr;

int main()
{
time_t start,end;
volatile long unsigned counter;
start = time(NULL);
for(counter = 0; counter < 500000000; counter++)
{}

int i;
char str1[]="XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-YYYYYYYY-TTTTTT";
char str2[]="pro1_0.0";
char str3[]="CC";
char str4[]="ZZ";
char str5[]="QQ";
char serialstring[100];
stderr = fopen("path to file","w");
//freopen("llog.out","w",stderr);

printf("enter a serial string:");
scanf("%s",serialstring);
if((strstr(serialstring,str1)))
{
printf("String1  matched\n");
  if((strstr(serialstring,str2)))
   {
   fprintf(stderr,"str2 matched\n"); //it is where i tried using fprintf and stderr, rest of code is working pretty file 
      if((strstr(serialstring,str3)))
       {
          printf("str3 matched\n");
         }
      else if((strstr(serialstring,str4)))
           {printf("str4 matched\n");}
      else if((strstr(serialstring,str5)))
           {printf("str5 matched\n");
for(i=232;i<290;i++)
{
printf("Sending some values: %d\n",i);}}
    }
   else{printf("str2 not matched\n");}
}
else{printf("str1 not matched\n");}

end = time(NULL);
        printf("The loop used %f seconds.\n", difftime(end, start));
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: See R..'s answer, but you should always check the result of `fopen()` or `freopen()` to ensure that the call succeeded.  You can get core dumps if the calls do not succeed and you try using a null pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dup2()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2):

```
int fd = open("mylog.txt", O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT);
if (fd < 0) {
     printf("Cannot open mylog.txt!\n");
     exit(1);
}
if (dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO) < 0) {
     printf("Cannot redirect stderr!\n");
     exit(1);
}
```

From this point on, any writes to stderr will go to `"mylog.txt"`.

You can use similar approach to redirect `stdout` as well - just use `STDOUT_FILENO`.

Comment: it worked out for me...and now stderr is quite clear, though it was very basic...but is important to be considered

Answer (score 6):

You are not supposed to try to override `stderr` yourself. Just use it. It's provided to you by the program that's running your program. If your program is being run interactively from a shell on a terminal, then both `stdout` and `stderr` normally go to the terminal, but there are plenty of ways that could be overridden. The most common way it's overridden is that the caller has redirected `stdout` to a file, to save the output, but left `stderr` connected to the terminal so that the user can see status/error messages.

Comment: so stderr is just like printing any error message on console.